# Flowchart: adding label in top of picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've got the following TikZ picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, scale=0.7, transform shape]
\node (start) [func-entry] {Config.getText(\textbf{key})};
\node (dec1) [decision, below of=start] {\textbf{key} in\\ \emph{localized \_labels?}};
\node (dec2) [decision, right of=dec1, node distance=4cm] {\textbf{key} in\\ \emph{default \_language \_labels?}};
\node (stop) [stop, right of=dec2, node distance=4cm] {Return \textbf{key}};
\node (stop2) [stop, below of=dec1, node distance=2.6cm, xshift=2cm] {Return its value};

\draw [arrow] (start) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=south] {No} (dec2);
\draw [arrow] (dec2) -- node[anchor=south] {No} (stop);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) |- node[anchor=east] {Yes} (stop2);
\draw [arrow] (dec2) |- node[anchor=west] {Yes} (stop2);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

which looks like this with my concrete node definitions:
[image: Result]

How do I add a label, like *localized_labels = /some/file/path/here* to the top or bottom of the picture without affecting the layout of the current nodes? I want the label to be included IN the picture (e.g. just doing it outside the tikzpicture is not ideal). I've tried drawing a node with [draw=none] at (0,0), but it draws on top of the existing nodes. What I want to do is to "shift" the current group of nodes down and then add the label in the top, but without affecting alignment of current nodes.

Comment: Please add complete, compilable examples, as your style definitions are lacking I can't compile your example.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three suggestions:

- You could add it relative to another node, for example

  ```
  \node [above=of dec2] {Whatever text you wanted};
  ```

  This requires `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`.
- You could place it relative to the current bounding box:

  ```
   \node [above=of current bounding box.north] {Whatever text you wanted};
  ```

  With this method you have to place the above line at the very end of the `tikzpicture`.
- You could specify the position. I think `(0,0)` is the default position for a node without coordinates, so your `start` node is probably in `(0,0)`. Hence, you could do

  ```
   \node at (2,1) {Whatever text you wanted};
  ```

  to place it two units to the right, and one unit above, the `start` node.

Comment: It works, but I would rather not couple the text to the alignment of the nodes below. Is there a way to avoid this? E.g. just placing text in (0.0) left-aligned while "pushing" the below nodes down 1 or 2 cm to make room for it?

Comment: @johnrl I added two more suggestions to my answer.

Comment: @johnrl Were any of my suggestions sufficient?